# Realm authentication throws [AppError: Network request failed] - React native

Tags: react-native, authentication, realm

```
async function logInUser() {
    try {
      await app.logIn(Realm.Credentials.anonymous());
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

I connected with realm and react native but when I try to authenticate, it throws [AppError: Network request failed]

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. That would indicate either the [React Native SDK Auth](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/manage-users/authenticate-users/#anonymous-user) code in your app is not set up correctly, or the server is not properly configured in the Realm Console. There's not much we can do to assist without troubleshooting and details. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)